# delete confirmation in php viewing the entry to be deleted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a delete form wherein the user will enter the pnum to be deleted and then it will delete the corresponding record. But I want the user to atleast see what would be deleted so I  tried this code, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
  <?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","nitoryolai123$%^");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE PNUM='{$_POST["pnum"]}'");
?>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form action="DeletebyPnumIn.php" method="post" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete "<?php echo $row["LASTNAME"]; ?>" )">
```

what might be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above does not include a line like:

```
$row = fetch_array($result);
```

You will need that for $row['LASTNAME'] to be set.

Otherwise, it looks like your code should work. You don't say how it doesn't work though. And it's hard to tell if this is the first page where they enter the pnum or a second page where the deletion is being confirmed. If it's the first page, you won't have the pnum to run the query on.

Instead of using javascript, you could have the original form post to a page that displays as much of the record information as you want to show the user. That page could have a simple "Are you sure..." form with buttons to delete or cancel.

Answer (score 2):

Your form is requiring the Submit action to know the contents of the to-be-deleted record before it submits. The way you've written it, this won't happen.

A javascript free way is something like this:

- have form1 with list of possible deletions and a Submit button called submit1
- process form1 and return form2 which shows the "Are you sure?" dialogue and has Submit button called submit2
- process form2 and delete record

If you want to use javascript, you have to add an AJAX function to your submit button that looks up the LASTNAME value.

//sidenotes

- you really need to sanitize your user input
- you should probably display a list of records with all their info rather than just allow pnums to be input.  That way you'll be less likely to get mistaken input and you'll already have LASTNAME available to your form

Comment: Great answer to an awkward question

Answer (score 1):

You must fetch your data using [mysq_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) for instance (of [mysql_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) but it's dirty imo).

And by the way : sanitize your input!